# React creating a button - non hardcoded properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a react button and here's the current code:

```
var React = require('react');

var buttonStyle = {
  margin: '10px 10px 10px 0'
};

var Button = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <button
        className="btn btn-default"
        style={buttonStyle}
        onClick={this.props.handleClick}>{this.props.label}</button>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Button;
```

The problem is that I don't want the className hardcoded, no the onclick.

I want to be able to add the classes and onclick event outside this code...for example:

```
<Button bStyle="myChosenStyles" onclick="myChosenFunction" />
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correctly pass className or click event handler to the props and then use it in component, e.g.:

```
var Button = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <button
        className={this.props.bStyle}
        style={buttonStyle}
        onClick={this.props.onclick}>{this.props.label}</button>
    );
  }
});

// use {} when passing myChosenFunction to the props
<Button bStyle="myChosenStyles" onclick={myChosenFunction} label="myLabel" />
```

You code currently has on click handler `handleClick` which is property of button component (you can simply change the name to `onclick`). With single or double quotes you can pass string variables (like `label`, or `className`). When you want to pass objects, functions, numbers, etc. you need to surround it with curly braces `{}`.